# Git Remote Pushing Nonexistent Files

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push changes to Github, but each time I get a warning that the files I'm pushing are too large.

Before I push my changes, I ran `git rm -r --cached .` to remove all of my files from the index. I've similarly included `cache/` in my `.gitignore`. However, when I try to commit and push my changes, it still tries to push these large files.

`remote: warning: File server/cache/0.12.2/osx32/... is 61.19 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB`

What gives?

Note: I'm the only one using this repository and I have backed up all of my work, so I felt safe using `git rm -r --cached`.

**Edit** - added gitignore and file structure.

**.gitignore**

```
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

*.dll
*.pak
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

standalone/
cache/
node_modules/
debug
~$*

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
Thumbs.db

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

Also, my directory structure is as follows:

```
.gitignore
server
--cache
--node_modules
```

Comment: can we see the ignore file please?

Comment: added the .gitignore file above

Comment: The repository holds by default all information necessary to checkout any commit.    So even if you make your _current_ commit small, you may still have large files stored for older commits.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository for how to rewrite the repository to get rid of these.

Comment: As a new user to .git/Github, I created a new repository and tried to push changes with both the files removed and the files specifically ignored in .gitignore. The files were still pushed to the repository, which failed because they were too large.

Comment: Also, Thor, your comment is well-received but starting a post off with a trick he learned from a post about "Advanced Linux techniques", namely 'lola', lost me at the very beginning.

Comment: @Himmel, see if they exist in your history at all, e.g. `git log server/cache/0.12.2/osx32/fileName`.